# In Ruby, is there a library to make command line scripts more user friendly, prompting me what to run?

Tags: ruby

So what I do now is my Ruby scripts have a bunch of methods, and I have to comment out which method calls I don't want to call, and un-comment the one I want to fire in my command line script.

Is there a Ruby library that makes it easy to prompt the user to which function to fire?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want code that will selectively execute a particular method in a source file, you'll need to write a dispatch table to take the input and call whichever routine is desired.

It's all pretty standard stuff for a programmer and easily done with [`OptionParser`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/classes/OptionParser.html) and some creative use of [`case/when`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000011) statements.

Comment: I have used option parser a few times and would say that this is definitely the way to go. See http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/optionparser.htm for an example of it in use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ARGV` to iterate over your program's arguments. There is also [`Getopt::Declare`](http://getoptdeclare.rubyforge.org/), which is a library for dealing with command line arguments in a similar fashion to traditional Unix utilities.

Answer (score 1):

If you need something that would really prompt user during the execution of the script, you can wrap the methods you need to prompt about:

```
module Confirmable
  def confirm_first *methods
    methods.each do |meth|
      alias_method "orig_#{meth}", meth
      define_method meth do |*args, &block|
        print "Execute #{meth}?[Yn] "
        s = gets.chomp
        return if s.downcase == 'n'
        send "orig_#{meth}", *args, &block
      end
    end
  end
end

class MyClass
  extend Confirmable
  def foo arg
    puts "starting foo"
    puts arg
  end

  confirm_first :foo
end

c = MyClass.new
c.foo "bar"
```

This way, each method that you mark with `confirm_first` will first ask you for confirmation before actually executing.